# Three.js - set different clear color when doing GPU ping-ponging

Tags: javascript, three.js

Trying to implement something using GPU ping-ponging in Three.js and I'm running into a weird issue where setting the clear color for the renderer seems to overwrite the output of the fragment shader responsible for rendering things out.

If I set the clear color to white, pixels go white. If I leave it at the default of black, pixels are correctly colored.

I would rather not have to draw a plane if I don't have to.

I'm not sure yet if this is a Three.js specific thing or if it's inherent in OpenGL ES2 as I did try setting the clear color directly (render.getContext().clearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0) ) but that ended up with the same result.

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: so are you wanting an alpa, or no bg all together...im confused

Comment: @Careen I'm not sure whats confusing? In short, I can't change the background without affecting what I'm trying to render using the GPU.
Not trying to affect background alpha, I just want to be able to freely change it's color.

Comment: That was a better way to explain it ...lol I got it 100% rename your question..  did you want to change its colour during run time to different colors a simple solution would be to use alpha bg and change css bg color with javascript by adding classes on the fly?

Comment: Do you have blending enabled?

Comment: @Careen, eh.... I don't think you get it still... I'm trying to change the renderer's background color, not the background color of the page

Comment: @RetoKoradi
Doh! That was it! haha, thanks! If you want to post that as a answer I'll mark it as correct and elaborate as best I can.

Comment: lol i got it now....

Comment: I find this question incredibly confusing. I am assuming you have your material, with your shader, set to transparent == true. If that is the case, then yes, three.js will take care of some stuff for you under the hood. Stuff like enabling the proper blend modes based on your material setting. You can still issue your own gl calls as well.

When blending happens, some math is done between the target and source pixels, and you get your result. Add .5 to 0 you get .5, add it to 1.0 you get 1.5. On screen this is clamped to 1.0. 

Calling clear will... clear everything.

Comment: @pailhead eh....I don't know whats confusing dude...tried setting a clear color to change the background, the new color was affecting what I was trying to render, turning off blending solved the issue.

Comment: It's confusing because you keep using the term 'background' which is, again, very misleading and confusing. I think you should be using terms like 'target', 'source', 'frame buffer'. "Background" is way more abstract, and the answer to this question is basically - renderer.setBackgroundColor( yourColor ). So instead of "i dont know whats confusing dude" you could have written "i am using a transparent material". The first statement is redundant, we already know that you dont know whats confusing. If you did, you probably wouldnt have written a confusing question.

Comment: I still have no idea whats going on and would love to see a screenshot. Even the comment above you say "I'm trying to change the renderer's background color, not the background color of the page". What blending has to do with all of this is beyond me.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound rude, but since this may come up for other people, this stuff is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color can affect your rendering if blending is enabled. If you do not need blending, disable it with:

```
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

If you do need blending, things can get slightly more complex. Some of the most commonly used blend functions, like the ever popular:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

work just fine with any background color. For example, with this blend function, if you render opaque red (alpha of fragment = 1.0) on top of a white background, you still get red.

Some other blend functions only really work on a black background. For example, if you use additive blending:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

rendering anything on top of a white background will just keep it white. Well, since it adds to white, it would be "whiter than white", but that only works in laundry detergent commercials. :)

Note that the code lines above would be for C/C++ bindings of OpenGL. I hope that they will translate easily to WebGL/Three.js.

Comment: to add on to this - if you're using Three.js, blending modes are specified as properties of the THREE object. You "turn on" blending by specifying the blending mode when you create your shader material.

Alternatively you can follow Reto's instruction as well by first getting a reference to the webgl context by calling (note "renderer" should be whatever the variable name you chose for your webgl renderer)  

`var gl = renderer.getContext()`  
then you can use the above functions like so  

`gl.disable(gl.GL_BLEND)`

Comment: How does this relate to the buffer clearing, ping ponging and "backgrounds"?

Comment: @pailhead
it relates because I'm specifically using and mentioning Three.js. Reto's answer only references generic opengl calls, which, the average Three.js user/tinkerer might not be able to translate into javascript.

Comment: @sortofsleepy I meant to add a disclaimer saying that the code lines are not for WebGL/Three.js. Even though it's probably obvious enough.

Comment: @RetoKoradi haha. No worries!

Comment: @sortofsleepy, i wasn't commenting on a comment, i was commenting on the answer. The question is about three.js 'backgrounds' and ping ponging. The answer is about GL calls. I think either the question needs to change in order to accommodate for this ("how do i enable blending func in webgl"), or this shouldnt be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

To set the color the three.js renderer clears to, use:

```
renderer.setClearColor ( color, alpha )
```

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer

In order to do the low level calls from the answer above, in three.js do this:

```
myMaterial.transparent = false;
```

Three.js will issue the correct calls when this object is about to be drawn.